# Access container contents from outside eg.Postman using different DNS name

Tags: linux, docker

I have a node js service inside the container. Usually, we can access it like `localhost:port/api/version`.
But instead, I want to access it from postman using `SomeCustomDomainname/api/version`.

I have already added an entry in `/etc/hosts` file but still can't access the endpoint.

Comment: Please share your `/etc/hosts` file content. Also the URL you are using on Postman to access the API. Add response received from POSTMAN as well.

Comment: /etc/host file                                                                                                         127.0.0.1       localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
127.0.0.1       testing.example.com
172.17.0.2      81d62c9ef0d0

Comment: Postman url i am using testing.example.com/api/version

Comment: looks like 172.17.0.2 is the internal ip address of the container? I guess that you expose the port of the container on your host as you wrote you access it via localhost. Same works with the hostfile, change the entry from 172.17.0.2 to 127.0.0.1 and if the target port is open the request should come through